# Zeppelin - run paragraphs in order

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have `spark 2.1` standalone cluster installed on 2 hosts.
There are two notebook's `Zeppelin(0.7.1)`:

- first one: preparing data, make aggregation and save output to files by:

  `data.write.option("header", "false").csv(file)`
- second one: notebook with shell paragraphs merge all part* files from spark output to one file

I would like to ask about 2 cases:

- How to configure Spark to write output to one file
- After notebook 1 is completed how to add relations to run all paragraphs in notebook2 eg:
  NOTEBOOK 1:

  `data.write.option("header", "false").csv(file)`

  "run notebook2"

  NOTEBOOK2:

  `shell code`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a paragraph at the end of note1 that executes note2 through Zeppelin API? You can optionally add a loop that checks whether all paragraphs finished execution, also through API.

Comment: Yes, I used z.run method. But the problem is with two different interpreters. From shell I can't use z.run. I solved it by (I know - it's now fancy way) using sleep command.